# sum of infinite series including log term

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can anyone tell me how to compute this sum over infinite series containing log like this-

$$D(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty} ^\infty \ln\left(\mu\sqrt{ (x_0-n\beta)^2+x_1^2}\right)$$.

The answer of the sum is the following. any clue how to do it?

$$D(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty} ^\infty \ln\left(\mu\sqrt{ (x_0-n\beta)^2+x_1^2}\right)=\ln\left(\mu\beta\sqrt{\cosh(\frac{2x_1\pi}{\beta}) - \cos(\frac{2x_0\pi}{\beta})}\right)$$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’m not sure if it converges. You are summing infinitely many $\ln \mu$.

Comment: Unless $\beta=0$ and $\mu \sqrt{x_0^2+x_1^2}=1$, it diverges, since the terms don't go to $0$ as $n \to \pm \infty$.  Are you talking about some summability method for divergent series?  If so, which one?